# How to add css property after disabling a check box in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi I want to disable a check box first, then i want to add a css property. I have written the below code. By this code the check box is disabled but the css property is not added.

```
 $("input:radio,input:checkbox").each(
     function (nitem,obj){        
         if (labelTag[0].nodeName == 'LABEL'){
             labelTag.click(function(ev){
                 $(this).prev().checkboxradio('disable').css("color","red");
        });
    }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="simple-checkbox chk">
     <input type="checkbox" id="billingaddress" class="radio">
         <label class="gray enableExpressCK" for="billingaddress">Enable Express Checkout</label>
 </div>
```

[jsFiddles here](http://jsfiddle.net/jRPTq/)

Comment: sorry I didn't get you... when the checkbox is checked you want to add a css property to the next label

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/j93Vu/

```
$("input:radio,input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this)
        .prop('disabled', true)
        .next('label')
            .css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

[Just a minor update:](http://jsfiddle.net/j93Vu/1/)

```
$("input:radio,input:checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this)
        .attr('disabled', 'disabled')
        .next('label')
            .css('color', 'red');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript is NOT working:

> ReferenceError: labelTag is not defined if (labelTag[0].nodeName ==
>   'LABEL') {